# MediaPlayer video not showing

Tags: android

I have this big problem with playing video on my app.
I have this game and wanted to show some videos somewhere but, in the best case I can hear the sound but not see the video.

this is the holder

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      level.playerholder = holder;              
      gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
      renderLoopThread.setRunning(true);
       gameLoopThread.start();
    renderLoopThread.start();               
 }
```

this is the creation of the mediaplayer and should show the video

```
while(!playerholder.isCreating());          
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(playerholder);


switch(startVideo){
case 1:
try {   
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.getfun.treevolve/raw/getfunvideo"));
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }




        Log.d("player", "Sec: " + Integer.toString(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));



        Log.d("player", "Video width: " + Integer.toString(mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth()));
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

With this settings my log shows only 0. Like the video is wrong.
If in the second line I delete the holder

```
 mediaPlayer.setDisplay(playerholder);
```

is working, all the info in the log are showing correctly but, I hear the audio but don't see anything.

Thank you for the help, I really need this. =)

Comment: I think for videos you should use `VideoView`

Comment: VideoView ask me for edit a layout xml file, but I don't have and I don't want use any layout. :-(

Comment: From the documentation: "MediaPlayer class can be used to control playback of audio/video files and streams. An example on how to use the methods in this class can be found in VideoView." You don't need an xml file, you can programmatically create a VideoView and add it to your Activity's view hierarchy at any time.

Comment: Hi, thank you  Karakuri. I'm trying to find some example on how to add VideoView programmatially. Can you link me something please? Thank you a lot

Comment: `videoView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`